# how to build mingw qt project in vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have project used Qt mingw to build, but I want to use it in visual studio 2017, but it can't work and occurred an error.

Microsoft says vs2017 can use gcc, but I can't find c++ compiler in my vs2017.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/c/2017/03/27/%E5%9C%A8visual-studio%E4%B8%AD%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E4%BB%BB%E4%BD%95c%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91%E5%99%A8

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @godlovemoon!

First: the given url is invalid.
Second: do you want to use the VisualStudio compiler tobuild the project, which was previously built with GCC. Or use the GCC inside VS as compiler?

Comment: I want to use gcc as complier inside  vs

Comment: @godlovemoon Ok, then - just like you already stated initially - this scenario is possible. Have you followed the advice from MS itself about how to configure everything? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/ - also this post looks like valid additional hints to make IntelliSense work properly: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/